# category theoretic approach to Sylow theorems and finite group theory?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, finite-groups

Is there a category theoretic approach to Sylow theorems?

More generally, is there an exposition of finite group theory in terms of category theory which would include Sylow theorems and little facts of the following sort (note use of counterexamples):

$A$ is abelian iff $\ <a,b>\longrightarrow <a,b:ab=ba> \rightthreetimes\ \ A\longrightarrow 1$

$G$ is perfect, $G=[G,G]$,  iff $G \not\rightarrow A$ for A abelian

finite group $H$ is soluble iff $G \not\rightarrow H$ for G perfect

(Cauchy theorem) $G$ has order prime to $p$ iff ${\Bbb Z}/p{\Bbb Z} \not\rightarrow G$

$G$ is a $p$-group iff $H \not\rightarrow G$ for groups $H$ of order prime to $p$

(Feit-Thompson theorem) ${\Bbb Z}/2{\Bbb Z} \not\rightarrow H$ implies  $G \not\rightarrow H$ for G perfect

Here $G \not\rightarrow H $ means there is no non-trivial homomorphism from $G$ into $H$.

For homomorphisms $f:A\longrightarrow B$ and $g:C\longrightarrow D$, the *lifting property*
$f \rightthreetimes\ \ g $ means that for each homorphisms $u:A\longrightarrow C$ and $d:B\longrightarrow D$
such that $fd=ug$, there is a morphism $ d': B\longrightarrow C$ such that $u=fd'$ and $d=d'g$.
For example,  $G \not\rightarrow H $ iff $G\longrightarrow 1 \rightthreetimes\   H \longrightarrow 1 $ iff  $1\longrightarrow H \rightthreetimes\  1 \longrightarrow H $.

Comment: Could you make precise what "category theoretic" means for you?

Comment: not really..I suppose anything which uses both category theory and Sylow theorems in an essential way, for example a reformulation of Sylow theorems in terms of category theory and/or diagram chasing.

Comment: I believe this is a good question and hope that some people who are interested in both groups and categories will think about it.   My hunch is that the key will be the second part of Sylow's theorem: the *number* of $p$-subgroups rather than their *existence*. The number is a corollary of the action of the group, which in turn is a form of Cayley's Theorem, *alias* the Yoneda Lemma.